# fetch data from json angular return object object

Tags: angular, typescript

I just try to fetch data from my json to be able to display it in my html, but it returns object object and I don't understand my error.

of course I imported httpclientmodule in the app.module.ts and I have an Itype interface.

**json.file**

```
"site": "site A",
"bus": [
    {
        "type": "1A",
        "weight": 500
    },
```

**service**

```
  public _url: string = '/assets/data/type.json';

  constructor(private htpp: HttpClient) { }

  getAllType(): Observable<Itype[]> {
    return this.htpp.get<Itype[]>(this._url);
  }
```

**ts.file**

```
typeArray: Itype[] = [];

  constructor(private typeService: TypeService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.typeService.getAllType()
      .subscribe(data => this.typeArray = data);
  }
```

**Itype interface**

```
export interface Itype

     site: string;
     bus:
        {
            type: string;
            weight: number
        }
```

**html**

```
  <th *ngFor="let type of typeArray">
           {{type}}
        </th>
```

Comment: Did you try to parse your response data? like .subscribe(data => this.typeArray = JSON.parse(data));

Answer (score 0):

You are specting an Array of Itype(with a site and a bus object), if you try to print that the way you are doing it with that `ngFor` you are printing ITypes. You need to print an specific property of the Itype(like `{{type.site}}`) not the entire object. HTML cannot print an object that's why you are getting `object object`

Comment: if I do {{type.site}} it works but not for bus.type why?

Comment: bus is an object itself inside the Itype you should use {{type.bus.type}}

Comment: there is nothing displayed

Comment: Can you provide an screenshot of the error or the actual code?

Comment: `<table style="border:1px solid black">     <thead>         <tr>             <th *ngFor="let type of typeArray">                {{type.bus.type}}             </th>         </tr>     </thead> </table>`